# Is there a way to clearly define hardware controller?

Tags: rhel, raid, system-information

### Background

There's a task to automate info grabbing from servers. However, I am unable to locate any hardware or software RAID controllers.

---

### Issue

Due to the various ways each vendor describes its controller, I am struggling to clearly define which block devices shown are RAID.

I assume the best way to resolve this issue would be to use built-in Linux utilities.

If my assumptions are wrong, please inform me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to there are many differences from vendor to vendor (and within the vendor) the way I choose is using two main instruments: `lspci` and `dmesg` by `grep`ping RAID. So, firstly I use the `lspci` command and, if it doesn't return sought output, I run `dmesg` with the same `grep`ping. That way is working for now for more than 20 machines with Hewlett Packard and MegaRAID controlles.

Comment: For now I derived one-liner (for lspci only):
```lspci -vmm | sed -E -n '/RAID bus|SCSI controller/,/^ *$/p' | tr -d '\t'```
Which print field like Class, Vendor, Device, SVendor (subvendor), SDevice (subdevice) and Rev. It works commonly for Hewlett Packard, LSI, Adaptec, 3Ware and LSI Fusion-MPT. Using this one-liner get rid of the need dmesg in most cases (except 1 machine where lspci doesn't work, but dmesg doesn't work too for weird errors' output)

Answer (score 2):

You can do that both ways, from devices names *as they are now standardized*  or detecting them from `dmidecode` or `lshw` command

also `cat /proc/mdstat`

also `lspci -knn | grep 'RAID bus controller'`

or `lshw -class disk`

There are many solutions & of course dedicated ones from external tools from manufacturers.

Comment: OK. I have known about this ways before, but my purpose was to find the one which will cover all possible options.
Due to there are many differences from vendor to vendor (and within the vendor) the way I choose is using two main instruments: lspci and dmesg by grepping RAID.
So, firstly I use the lspci command and, if it doesn't return sought output, I run dmesg with the same grepping. That way is working for now for more than 20 machines with Hewlett Packard and MegaRAID controlles.